# Creating classes from qualified name in the database

Tags: java, database

I'm working on a smarthouse project which has an array of devices that communicate over wireless adapter connected to serial port. At startup I want to load the remote device list from a database, where their qualified names are stored (example of remote devices are Door sensor,Movement sensor, Heating system...). All remote devices are child class of `RemoteDevice` class because they are using the same hardware to communicate.

The problem is at runtime I don't know which devices are there going to be in the database, and this should be done dynamically. I've found other examples that would suggest this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Class clazz = Class.forName("test.Demo");
        Demo demo = (Demo) clazz.newInstance();
```

However I don't know which class will I get (there can be dozen of device types), and my classes don't have default constructor. My loading method looks like this

```
public void loadDatabase(Connection dbConn) throws SQLException
{
    String query = "SELECT * FROM smartHouse.device AS dev ";

    try
    {
        Statement statement = dbConn.prepareStatement(query);
        ResultSet devices = statement.executeQuery(query);

        while(devices.next())
        {
            int id = devices.getInt("id");
            String address = devices.getNString("HW Address");
            String classpath = devices.getNString("ClassPath");
            //parse classpath, create remote object instances and add them to device ArrayList
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: "and my classes don't have default constructor" - well how would you know what arguments to pass to the constructor then?

Comment: Using reflection is expensive, insecure and not justified in this case. You can create a factory ([pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern)) that receives a device name and returns an instance of the relevant class.

Comment: Factory design pattern is the way to go ;)

Comment: @alfasin exactly and the safer

Comment: Jon under default constructor i meant constructor that takes no arguments, that was bad explanation on my side. The constructor always takes Hardware address and id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about a factory method like this:

```
RemoteDevice createDevice (String className, String hardwareAddress) {
    Class clazz = Class.forName(className);
    RemoteDevice newDevice = (RemoteDevice) clazz.newInstance();
    newDevice.setHardwareAddress(hardwareAddress);
}
```

This would obviously need the setter "setHardwareAddress" in the base class "RemoteDevice" and a default constructor in every inheritor.

If you have always the same arguments in your constructor, your factory method could look like that:

```
RemoteDevice createDevice (String className, String hardwareAddress) throws Exception {
    Class clazz = Class.forName(className);

    Constructor<RemoteDevice> constructor = clazz.getConstructor(new Class[]{String.class});
    RemoteDevice result = constructor.newInstance(hardwareAddress);
    return result;
}
```

Does it help?

Comment: This clarifies things a bit however one thing is still unclear to me; if i upcast e.g. TemperatureSensor to RemoteDevice will the overridden methods be available to me. Thing that concerns me is this: Both RemoteDevice and Temperature sensor have the method called parseNotification which handles notification from the remote device. Remote device just logs it, while TemperatureSensor parses input, does some calculation etc. So if i call RemoteDevice.parseNotification(some args) on upcasted Tempreature sensor will the RemoteDevice method respond or will TempreatureSensor method respond

Comment: I've been digging on and i've found the answer, and the thing you wrote fits in. Thank you a lot.